# Recorded sound is not playing with CocosDenshion

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, avaudiorecorder

I recording voice with AVAudioRecorder (with this tutorial http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/avaudiorecorder?before=1300075871 ) and then try to play recorded sound with CocosDenshion:

```
CDSoundEngine* soundEngine = [[CDSoundEngine alloc] init];
NSArray *defs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],nil];
[soundEngine defineSourceGroups:defs];
//......
[soundEngine loadBuffer:1 filePath:[recorder.url path]];
[soundEngine playSound:1 sourceGroupId:0 pitch:2.0f pan:0 gain:1.0f loop:NO];
```

This code works fine on simulator, but on device (iPad 2, iOS 5.1.1)- sound is not playing.
I'll try to play recorded sound with AVAudioPlayer - its playing fine, but I need to pitch sound and found thats using CocosDenshion is simplest way for that.
What settings or something other should I check or fix to play recorded sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, first I've changed the way to create CDSoundEngine instance, to use CDAudioManager:

```
CDSoundEngine = [CDAudioManager sharedManager].soundEngine;
```

Then, before playing recorded sound set mode for CDAudioManager to kAMM_PlayAndRecord:

```
[CDAudionManager sharedManager] setMode:kAMM_PlayAndRecord];
```

And finally redirect AudioSession to speakerphone:

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

and all worked fine.